# React Native - How to use Promises with async

Tags: react-native

I'm pretty new of RN but I don't really understand Promises with async.
I got how works but I don't use them correctly cause they don't work in my code.
Example

```js
 const getAnimationTime = () => {
  let res = meditationTime;
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve(res));
};
```

and then:

```js
 useEffect(() => {
      (async function fetchData() {
        const fetcher = await getAnimationTime();
        console.log('fetcher', fetcher);
        setAnimationTime(fetcher);
      })();
      console.log('anitime useEffect', animationTime);
    }, []);
```

I did what I saw in tutorials and doesn't work. In this case, I always get `undefined`

Can someone explain to me how works?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting `undefined` error when you log `fetcher` or during `console.log('aniTime useEffect', animationTime);` this line?

Comment: Hi thanks. I updated the code and like this I get always `undefined` . 1 log from `fetcher` and 4 from `anitime`. Then the both of them get the time

Comment: I have added an answer. One more question what is the value of `meditationTime`.

Comment: that value come from a screen and I get it with: `route.params.time `

Comment: Ok. I have used static value in my answer. Please check is it working?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move variable declared inside the `Promise` block.

```js
const getAnimationTime = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let res = 100;
    resolve(res);
  })
};
```

Comment: I tried with your `value` but it doen't change. `fetcher` never gets `undefined` but `aniTime` does

Comment: Means you are getting value in `console.log('fetcher', fetcher);` this log. but not in `aniTime`. If this the case than I guess you must be having issue with `setAnimationTime(fetcher);`

Comment: Yes I meant that. `aniTime` gets `undefined` twice. But witch problem?

Comment: I tried also await `setAnimationTime(fetcher);` but it doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

I solved like adding this:

```
  if (isLoading || animationTime === null) {
    return <PulseIndicator color="green" size={50} />;
  } else {
  return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={handlePause}
        onLongPress={longPress}
        style={styles.container}>
...
```

It simply waits for the changing state